# Store Javascript Delta object in database

Tags: javascript, quill

im using the Quill text editor which returns a Delta object representing the content.

https://quilljs.com/

i want to store this in a database but am unable to convert it to a string/json type format

```
deltaobject.toString
```

The above returns

```
[object object]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the native JSON converter...

```
var json = JSON.stringify(deltaobject);
```

then to convert it back to an object...

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

```js
var json = JSON.stringify({ prop1: "Value1", property2: 123.456 });
console.log(json);

var obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: ill give that a go now, any idea how to return it back to delta from the string?

Comment: I was just adding that, with a snippet :)

Comment: ha, i noticed about a second after posting. That all works perfectly. Thank for your help

Comment: No worries - happy to help :)